# Managing the order of <head> viewlets in Plone

Tags: plone

How one can manually shuffle the order of `<head>` viewlets and see currently enabled registrations in Plone? Naturally these viewlets are not visible on *@@manage-viewlets* page.

I have an issue where Products.TinyMCE has managed to register its configuration viewlet before other `<head>` viewlets on the site. I'd like to know how to manually fix the problem.

https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13239